# disable caching on a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have checked this thread.
[Disable browser cache for entire ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache)

And wondering if I can put the answer inside page_load ?

If not how do I disable the cache on for a single page?

Thanks!

Comment: For aspx pages, they are not cached by browser by default. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think they are cached... or am I missing something? The page actually has a meta tag like this.
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 12:12:02 GMT">
And the information typed on this page is cached . Is it something different?

Comment: Do you have server side cache? you can use fiddler or charles to see if browser request the resource from server side.

Comment: Yes, I think the issue is the serverside, rather than client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And wondering if I can put the answer inside page_load ?

Yes you can as long as you have not set same Header before.

At the end you can place them, and check if your page get the cache header by inspecting the headers on the browser (chrome and firefox have utilities for that)

Comment: So I have to remove the headers 
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"> <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 12:12:02 GMT">

And I can use the code ?

Comment: @rlee923 Yes, I think is better to add the cache to the header and not inside the html header code. In my pages I set the cache on every page (or one time on master page)

Comment: Thanks a lot !  (15 char req)

Comment: Instead of answering "yes" it would be nice to have an answer with at lease 1 code example.

Comment: @Mike Happy New Year for 2017. The code that you say is here on the question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/disable-browser-cache-for-entire-asp-net-website  so I will not place probably to not anyone say that I copy paste the answer.