# how to disable cache?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net mvc disable browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache)

how to disable cache for a method in asp.net mvc3?

Problem in IE9
I am saving some data on /home/ page. The page saves data and reload the page to show the newly updated result. In other browsers FF/Opera page refresh is getting new results but on IE9 its showing old data.

Comment: Are you sure it's MVC that's caching the page and not your proxy/browser? How are you accessing the page (GET or POST)?

Comment: By default there is no cache in ASP.NET MVC 3, so your question hardly makes any sense without providing more details. Are you talking about browser cache or something? Details please. Are you currently experiencing some problems with a code you would like to share?

Comment: See my prior post at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache/5546328#5546328

Comment: IE9 does not go back for ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Comment: If you use this, you may find the following blog useful: [Beware-the-ASP.NET-SetCacheability-method](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/04/01/Beware-the-ASP.NET-SetCacheability-method.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just reload the page with some random parameter.

Like: /home/?rd=**2823772**

Make sure to always change the rd parameter to another random number on each reload. This way, IE9 will not have the page cached and it'll refresh like FF/Opera.

Comment: If user presses back button in IE9 for example, the link will not be random. Anyway a good approach would be using either change the port, so the Action Method gets refreshed. Another way is to either use Outputcache which is limited, or create a NoCacheAttribute for that method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache