# Back button not requesting asp.net mvc get method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

We are facing a specific problem where in on click of backbutton, the default get method is not getting triggered in asp.net mvc

any specific solutions ?

Comment: could you give us a little more information? the code?

Comment: Is this Browser Back or a button you placed on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the browser has the page cached, it'll use the one from cache.

Try telling the response not to cache.  You can do it with an ActionFilter or globally in Global.asax.

```
    httpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    httpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    httpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    httpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    httpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

More options here:

[Disable browser cache for entire ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache)

Comment: I tried the above and it does not work. anything i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

if you want just one specific action to get from server every time use

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1)]
```

as an attribute on your action like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ........
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your HTML  section:

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

That will stop the page from being cached by your browser.

Comment: that should be in your HTML "HEAD" section