# How to disable server-side caching on IIS 7.5 (asp net mvc3)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7.5

I'm struggling with my IIS setup regarding caching, here's a brief description of my problem:

I'm making a site for mobile and non-mobile, sharing the same controllers. IE: mysite/page will serve either mysite/page.cshtml, or mysite/M/page.cshtml, depending on the device.

Here's the catch, it worked fine with my local and integration environment (cassiini and iis 6), but on another machine (2008r2/iis 7.5), apparently there is an aggressive *server-side* caching policy:

- If I access the website from a desktop machine, I have the correct pages (desktop version)
- If now I use my mobile phone to access the site, I will have the desktop version, (which implies a server-side cache, my phone is not using the same network).

On the contrary, if I were to restart the server and access the site using my phone first, then I will get the mobile version on my desktop (only for the pages I already visited of course).

I tried 2 solutions so far:

Disabling OutputCache from my Web.config:

```
<httpModules>
  [..]
  <remove name="OutputCache" />
</httpModules>
```

And unchecking "Enable output cache" in "Output Caching" for my site in IIS.

What's bugging me is that I do not have this problem with my other server (iis 6.0), although caching is enabled on this one, which leads me to think it is related to iis 7 caching addition.

My question is simple: **how does one disable server-side caching on IIS 7.5?**

Thanks in advance for your iis lights!

## Found it!

Sorry guys you could not really guess that one, I extend RazorViewEngine (actually I used a sample mobile mvc3 template app), and this class overrides FindView, it is supposed to take into account a useCache parameter, but apparently no matter how I configure IIS, it was set to true with iis7. I set it to false everywhere. I'll look into appropriate tuning of that parameter tomorrow.

```
public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
```

Thanks for your help guys, I have a good understanding of all the caching possibilities with IIS now ;). It's interesting that this behaves differently with IIS 7.0 (IIS6 and Cassiini were consistent).

Edit:

More info: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8201?PendingVoteId=8201 , it is related to debug/release working of FindView.

This was my exact problem: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8201?PendingVoteId=8201

Comment: hard to guess without knowing you are extending the engine : )

Comment: I forgot to add that in the equation, I did not suspect MVC could be caching the view resolution itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking to static types such as images and such you can add this to your web.config

```
 <staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache"/>
</staticContent>
```

Update:

Here is a [link](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching?showTreeNavigation=true)

This link talks in detail about what you want to do.

Comment: I do want static content caching, the problem is caching the dynamic pages.

Comment: I added to my answer on how to tackle dynamic content caching

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was also reading but that did not seem to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

As Rick said, you need to profile this first. A quick test though would be to implement a no-cache controller as I outlined here:
[Disable browser cache for entire ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache/5546328#5546328)

Comment: I did that, no change, however I noted that somehow the non mobile version prevails, as soon as I load a non mobile version of a page, whatever the browser/computer/phone, it's all going to be rendered as a non desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with browser cache.  Have you profiled the traffic to see the 304s? You may be chasing the wrong problem.

*NOTE: Your cache busting solution has to include the client side as well as the server-side.*

Comment: I have that problem when I use separate browsers, this excludes browser cache issues. (browser2 is mobile and gets the page from browser1 which is not mobile)

Comment: You need to monitor the HTTP responses to know what is happening.  Looking visually at the pages on different devices isn't very reliable.

Comment: I'm trying to disable OutputCache as you suggested, unfortunately I don't know how to monitor the HTTP status code on my android, but I get 200s on the desktop.