# Does this method do what it says it will do (prevent the page from being cached)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter, authorize-attribute

```
private void PreventPageFromBeingCached(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
    cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
}
```

The reason I ask is that I originally had the following code in a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
private void PreventPageFromBeingCached(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
    cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
    cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null);
}

protected void CacheValidateHandler(
    HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
{
    //todo validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
}
```

I basically pasted this code from an answer on StackOverflow a while ago, and I have since moved this logic to an `IAuthorizationFilter`.

The problem is, by switching to an interface, I've lost `AuthorizeAttribute`'s implementation of `OnCacheAuthorization`. According to the docs, `OnCacheAuthorization` is "called when the caching module requests authorization." This doesn't really tell me what I would need to do to implement this method, or if I even need the callback in the first place.

**Questions**

1. Will `PreventPageFromBeingCached` actually prevent the page from being cached with just the two lines of code or do I need to also include `cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null);` and the `CacheValidateHandler()` method (plus an implementation of `OnCacheAuthorization()`)?
2. If I do need the extra code, what exactly does it do?
3. If I have it all wrong, how do I prevent a page from being cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like the controller approach as I've specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache/5546328#5546328)

You don't have the issues you are concerned about the best I've been able to tell through using this in my apps as you are using client caching.

Comment: Thanks, that helps simplify things *a lot*.