# How to set the Expires date/time header in ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, expires-header

I have a portal that pulls data from a data source which is updated every day at 1am. So I want to set the expiration on the ajax calls that request the data from my asp.net mvc controller to expire at 2 am.

How do I set a specific date/time for expiration on the controller that is called by the ajax function?

Comment: What about using the `HttpCachePolicy.SetExpires` method: `Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Parse("2:00:00AM"));`?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234044/asp-net-mvc-and-ie-caching-manipulating-response-headers-ineffective

Comment: Ok I set that, but for some reason it is being ignored. IO also set Cache-Control and it is also being ignored. The headers I am getting back are Cache-Control: private and the expires is a date/time that isn't what I specified.