# Switch off form caching in asp .NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to switch off page caching in MVC3. Have tried:

```
@{
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0 "); 
 }
```

But hasn't worked. Thanks.

---

Just realised I may be asking for the wrong thing. I want to disable form history such that options previous values are not shown when populating a form field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `autocomplete='off'` to your input tags:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" ... />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ModelState.Clear();  in your action to clear model state:

```
public ViewResult YourAction(YourModel model) 
{
    .........
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(model); 
}
```

Comment: Had the same problem.  I think this one is the best answer if you are using ASP MVC

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your action inside the controller

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult Test() {
 ...
}
```

Ive had similar issues, that should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm.. still. Maybe switching off caching isn't what I want. I want to disable form history.

Comment: What chain of events cause it to show previous values? If you dont pass in a model or a null model then all text box's should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Using following JQuery works:

```
$(':text').attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Add it inside `$(document).ready()`