# No-cache HTTP header unable to override cache behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I was looking for a solution where I want to disable default behaviour of a browser and found a very nice solution for this: [asp.net mvc disable browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1705113/713208).

But this solution does not work for me. These are the headers passed:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  5026
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Fri, 25 Oct 2013 06:57:47 GMT
Expires -1
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 4.0
x-powered-by    ASP.NET
```

It's very clear for browser not to  store the page in cache but still if I click on the previous button I am able to see the previous pages after log out.

Comment: Did you clear your browser history? Your browser will still have the page cached from when it was allowed to cache it.

Comment: What caching headers does the page you're going back to emit?

Comment: Hi, did you perhaps override OnResultExecuted instead of OnResultExecuting?