# *Where* to set caching headers for HTML responses in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, browser-cache

I want to prevent browsers from caching HTML pages [which they unfortunately do by default](https://mixmax.com/blog/chrome-back-button-cache-no-store).

I understand the headers I need to set. But *where* in my ASP.NET MVC app is the appropriate place to set them?

The controllers do not seem right since that would be repetitive code and controllers can send non-HTML responses as well (e.g. JSON).

`BeginRequest` appears too broad since that would affect resources (and anything else I might not realize).

The suggested duplicate does not solve this issue: I only want to affect HTML pages (not the entire site) and the duplicate does not say *where* to add this code (it says "add where needed").

Comment: In MVC, the most appropriate place to put [cross-cutting concerns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658105.aspx) are in [filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(vs.98).aspx). For your simple example, you could just subclass `ActionFilterAttribute` and override `OnActionExecuting` to write the header, and then register the filter globally in `FilterConfig.cs`.

Comment: @NightOwl888 where would I apply that attribute? Is there no way around applying it *everywhere*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable browser cache for entire ASP.NET website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/disable-browser-cache-for-entire-asp-net-website)

Comment: In your `FilterConfig.cs` file, you only need to add your filter once and then it is applied on every request. There is then no need to add it everywhere.